# Storing word list in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, storage

I have previously made an anagram solver where if you gave a set of 9 letters, the program would find every possible 3-9 letter word that could be made out of those 9 letters.

I made this in javascript, where a word list of 100,000+ words were stored in a single array form which suitable answers could be found.

To find every subword of a 9 letter set, the program would only need to search through the whole array once, meaning that no matter what 9 letter set of letters you gave the program, the list of subwords were always given in under a second.

I am now making the same program but in objective-c as part of an ios app i intend to make.

Would there be any issues in storing a 100,000+ word list in an NSArray in objective-c?
Issues such as memory usage, look up speeds etc.

Are there any better ways of storing this word list that would make lookups faster or perhaps use less memory.

(I am a novice in objective-c)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to try it and see. You can then use Instruments.app to see the performance.

You may find [Alternative Objective-C object allocation for large arrays](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/08/alternative-objective-c-object.html) a worth while read.